# Функция сложения чисел через замыкание

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток. Очень интересует такой вопрос: как через замыкание создать функцию которая, например, складывает числа таким образом:

```
function sum(a){
    return function(b){
        return a + b;
    }
}

console.log(sum(5)(6)); //11
```

только чтоб можно было складывать больше 2х скобок, например, sum(2)(3)(4)(5)...N

Comment: погодите, у меня дежа вю?

Comment: если где-то есть такой вопрос , тогда скиньте пжл ответ)

Comment: @Igor, периодически всплывают :-)

Comment: @AlexKrass, почему же? например мой ответ вполне решает его задачу

Comment: та не, никаких извращений) такой вопрос по замыканиям был у меня на собеседовании и он поставил меня в тупик) вот хочу узнать ответ

Comment: @Grundy да решает, но как по мне, это все равно извращения, как бы вы ни пытались это отрицать))

Comment: @AlexKrass, можно сказать, на практике я не сталкивался с таким :-) но в теории вполне нормально выглядит :)

Comment: а есть какой то более элегантный вариант решения?

Comment: @Maksim, в чем измерять элегантность? :-) в общем случае подход один: возвращать новую функцию, возможно себя же, с переписанным  toString или valueOf и замкнутым значением

Comment: и заодно подскажите пожалуйста какие практические (реальные) задачи можно решать таким образом?

Comment: @Maksim, я не зря назвал это извращением. Хотел бы я посмотреть на лицо работодателя, если бы вы ему потом все задачи подобным образом решали)) На самом деле задача на теоретическое знание потайных уголков JS, в реальности почти не встретится, в отличие от простых замыканий. У Вас должны быть действительно веские основания, что бы писать такое. В остальном, чем код читабельней и проще, тем лучше. Могу порекомендовать почитать книгу Стоян Стефанов — «JavaScript. Шаблоны», там вроде было и про замыкания что-то.

Comment: @AlexKrass, так-то работодателю все равно как написан код - если работает, то хорошо.

Comment: @Grundy Работодателю да, а тем, кто будет его потом сопровождать нет. Вполне возможно, это будете Вы сами спустя пару лет, когда уже все забудете. Как говорится: "пишите код так, как будто сопровождать его будет склонный к насилию психопат, который знает, где вы живёте" ~©~ John C. Woods

Answer (score 5):

Чем-то напоминает кату из CodeWars, но попроще.

```js
function sum(n){
  sum.result += n;
  
  return sum;
}
sum.result = 0;
sum.valueOf = sum.toString = _ => sum.result;

console.info(sum(1)(2)(3));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47585/discussion-on-answer-by-other-----).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Выражаю протест - мне не предлагали создать чат. Остальным, думаю, тоже. Подчёркивается необходимость добавления этой ссылки вне зависимости от желания системы намекнуть.

Comment: Странно, обычно после 20-ти комментариев система предлагает перейти в чат.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, мной замечено - только если двое переписываются. Если третья сторона вмешивается - никакой ссылки не будет.

Answer (score 4):

Подход при создании функций, которые можно вызывать подряд неизвестное заранее число раз довольно стандартен:

1. Чтобы результат можно было вызвать как функцию, нужно вернуть функцию
2. Чтобы все-таки была возможность получить результат, нужно переопределить у возвращаемой функции методы [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf), [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString), какой-нибудь один, либо все сразу.
3. И самое главное - нужно хранить где-то результат, который можно вернуть переопределенными функциями.

Из соседнего ответа видно, что возвращать можно *исходную* функцию, у которой переопределены соответствующие методы. И результат хранится в поле самой функции.

Недостаток такого подхода в том, что состояние - глобально, и изменив вручную поле result, можно сломать последующие цепочки.

Так же, можно сразу использовать внутреннюю функцию, и хранить результат, не в ее поле, а в замкнутой переменной, например так:

```js
function sum(a) {
  var s = a;

  function innerSum(b) {
    return sum(a + b);
  };
  innerSum.toString = innerSum.valueOf = function() {
    return s;
  }
  return innerSum;
}

console.info(sum(1)(2)(3));
```

В этом случае идет предположение, что функции принимают *только* один аргумент. Если нужно расширить решение, чтобы любая функция могла принимать *несколько* аргументов, нужно внутри применить к ним функцию [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), для применения конкретной функции ко всем переданным параметрам, например так:

```js
function sum(...params) {
  var s = params.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

  function innerSum(...innerParams) {
    return sum(...innerParams.concat(s));
  };
  innerSum.toString = innerSum.valueOf = function() {
    return s;
  }
  return innerSum;
}

console.info(sum(1, 2)(3, 4)(5, 6));
console.info(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)); // все еще работает
console.info(sum(1)(2, 3)(4, 5, 6));
```

Comment: Странно видеть spread и обычные функции. А метод хранения хорош, хотя и слегка многословен, раз в условии нет "защитить результат".

Comment: @Other, а мне нравятся обычные функции :-) в стрелочных нет д̶у̶ш̶и - _this_, хотя он тут и не используется :-)

Comment: Так в этом и соль. Стрелки легче, быстрее и меньше писать. Ведь тут нет `this`, `super` или `arguments`.

Comment: @Other, кстати, плохо смотрел :-) у меня они в reduce используются, а остальное - копипаст с предыдущего решения :)

Comment: Я не сказал что все **не**стрелки, а что таковые есть, хотя, вроде, и не нужны.